# How do I know how much of a video is loaded by a NetStream in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, netstream

I'm making a video player in AS3 and was wondering how to find out how much of the video is currently cached/buffered. I'm not sure what the correct terminology is, so I haven't been able to find it in the documentation.

`NetStream.time` gives me the current location of the video, so based on that I can display a progressbar.

Underneath the progressbar, I want to display how much of the video has been loaded already. How do I find this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`NetSteam.bytesLoaded`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#bytesLoaded) and [`NetSteam.bytesTotal`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#bytesTotal) to get the total rough percentage loaded:

```
var bufferPercent:Number = myNetStream.bytesLoaded / myNetStream.bytesTotal;

// Use percentage to scale buffer bar.
myBufferBar.scaleX = bufferPercent;
```

Comment: Thanks! as a followup question, do you have any idea how I can clear my local cache/buffer? It seems that between development builds, flash has some sort of cache so it is difficult to test the buffer-related code...

Comment: @joon Hmm, not sure. But you can use the bandwidth profiler and live simulation when compiling to see how it works which may help.